# IE11 opening F12 JIT exception

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer-11, jit

When I press F12 in IE11 (v.11.1016.18362.0) to open developer tools first time it shows an exception with text

> Check dependency list! Syncronous require cannot resolve module
> 'serviceHub'. This is the first mention of this module!) [3040]
> iexplore.exe.

Sometimes if I need to debug JS, it shows that error window about 5-10 times and I close it one after one...

[image: Exception window]

I tried:

1. Removed and install again IE11 in windows components
2. Replaced files in C:\Windows\System32\F12\
3. Installed all Windows updates
4. Disabled all extensions and helpers in IE settings.

What else can I try?

When I tried to debug it, I see an exception in  with text

> "There was no method handler registered for the
> 'getTranslatedLocation' method."
> [image: debugging]

But I have no plugins in IE enabled anymore.

Comment: Which versions of OS and VS are you using? Do you want to use IE built-in debugger or the Visual Studio debugger? If you want to use the Visual Studio debugger, you can also try to reinstall or update your VS and enable Just-In-Time Debugging according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/k8kf6y2a(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). I think the serviceHub error is more related with Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you for comment! I tried to debug it with VS2019, but also have installed VS 2010 and 2012.. Windows 10.

Comment: Please check if there's any updates with VS2019 and try to test with environment which only has VS2019 correctly installed. Maybe it is related with the multi versions of VS in your machine or there're some issues with your VS2019.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was just to set checkboxes "Disable debugging (Internet Explorer)" and "Disable debugging (others)" in IE11 settings.